# React router not rendering the component through history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
import { React } from "react";
import { Router as MyRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import Article from "./Components/Article";
import Articles from "./Components/Articles";

var createBrowserHistory = require("history").createBrowserHistory;
const history = createBrowserHistory();

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyRouter history={history}>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Articles} />
          <Route exact path="/home/:title/:id" component={Article} />
        </Switch>
      </MyRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I have a component which display a list of articles, and if you click on one of the articles, you will be redirected to the specifics of that article. **Also, article is fetching the content from the server only using the id parameter**. I implemented that by using

```
const history = useHistory();
const onclick = (title, id) =>{
    history.push(`/home/${title}/${id}`);
}
```

Initially, I am having no trouble at all with this structure. However, when I added a random test article, and click on it, the url changes, but the component is never rendered(I tried to log "hello world" in the Article component but it never got printed out).  Strangely, if I manually put in the url `localhost:3000/home/fijdaifjaid/100` with some random title and the correct id(the id that router fails to render the component for), the component is rendered with no issue, but if I manually put in the correct title it does not work.(My title is "# 1 priority")

Any suggestion on what is the problem here? Also I should note this is not a universal problem, I have several other test ids that are working fine.

My dependencies:

```
 "react": "^17.0.2",
 "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import { React } from "react";
import { Router as MyRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import Article from "./Components/Article";
import Articles from "./Components/Articles";

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyRouter >
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Articles} />
          <Route exact path="/home/:title/:id" component={Article} />
        </Switch>
      </MyRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Since you are using `Router` as a wrapper of your application, what if you don't pass the `history` object on the `Router` since you will be using the react hook `useHistory()`.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is the title that is messing with my routes. My title is "#1  priority", if I deleted "#", it seems to be working fine. Is "#" something  like a preserved character?

Comment: @lyx yes. You need to urlencode the title (or any string) before passing to history.

Comment: @Iyx # is usually used for hashRouting you can read more here `https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of router use browser router :

```js
import { React } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as MyRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./Components/NavBar";
import Article from "./Components/Article";
import Articles from "./Components/Articles";

// var createBrowserHistory = require("history").createBrowserHistory;
// const history = createBrowserHistory();

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Articles} />
          <Route exact path="/home/:title/:id" component={Article} />
        </Switch>
      </MyRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Before making the build don't forget to add homepage in your package.json :

```json
"homepage": "https://xxxxx.github.io",
```